# How to find out what payloads are being uploaded when I am running a scan of remote website?

Tags: vulnerability-scanners, network-scanners, file-upload, web-scanners

I have been running an Acunetix vulnerability scan of a remote website (containing 50 subdomains). I am not doing anything else on this system.

However, my system is connected to a remote VPS via VPN, because it is the company's policy.

But I am confused. Is it normal that 9GB of data is uploaded during website vulnerability scanning? How can I find out what exact payload is being uploaded to what IP?

Comment: The scanner logs should record all of that. Otherwise, you should run a packet capture to see what's going on on the network.

Comment: In general scanners update the User-Agent field so you can identify easily on the logs. Depends on the scanner and how aggressive is the amount of data that sends may vary